# Whats the difference between ServerFault and SuperUser?

Tags: support

Whats the difference between ServerFault and SuperUser? Aren't they both for SysOps questions? Wouldn't it be prudent to have a mission statement for each site clearly visible?

Comment: By "mission statement", do you mean [the FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)?

Comment: Um..yes ****embarressed****

Comment: @GeneM., Why? [The terse FAQ's are pretty vague](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/what-questions-belong-on-super-user-vs-server-fault/28228#comment817225_28228) and open to interpretation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The FAQ for SU and SF contain the mission statement for either site:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users....
>
> Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.

If it involves managing servers, in a *professional setting* it goes there.

Most computer questions, outside the stuff you shouldn't ask on SE anyway (purchase recommendations and such) would fit here. Questions involving PCs, home networking and tablets are a safe bet.  If it's a phone, you'd be better off on the [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com) or [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com) [SE](http://stackexchange.com) sites.

SF, on the other hand, is a good place for questions which involve system administration. It is very helpful to get to understand their site culture, realize that these guys while occasionally cranky know their crap. If you ask stuff that involves wrangling computers, in a professional setting, and chances are you will find someone who happens to know the material at hand.

It's a good place to ask questions where, you've tried and documented 90% of the problem, are still stuck, and need a little push. It's *not* a nice place for folks who want to be spoon-fed. It's just how they roll.

Comment: I need new glasses I'm afraid. Thanks for at least not down voting my question; I feel silly now.

Comment: Serverfault is for BOFHS, Superuser is for lusers.

Comment: Downvoting wouldn't have an effect on MSU anyway, we don't have rep independent of the main site, like MSO does. Was a *challenging* question to answer, since telling you to read the faq felt like cheating ;p

Comment: Journeyman, By this, are you saying that the **content** of the questions on SU are actually [on-topic in SF, and vice-versa](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/what-questions-belong-on-super-user-vs-server-fault/28230#comment817194_28230)? Why are the sites split based on the [messenger](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent/3545#3545) instead of the [message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate/23326#23326)?

Comment: I still don't really get it (and I've checked both FAQs).  As I'm both a professional and hobbyist this answer seems to suggest that I pick the site based on whether I'm working on a client project or a personal project, even though the nature and content of the question could be the same in both cases.  Or, to put it another way, describing the difference between the sites based on *who* they are for (as opposed to *what* they are for) is not very helpful if you fit both descriptions.